# Overflow, indeterminate, or infinity errore in numerics

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I need your help once again. I am trying to calculate some numerical stuff with Mathematica and always run into the following error:

> NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand [...] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{7.36315*10^13, 1.10447*10^14}}"

My integral is of the following form (details are negligible, has to be convergent in any case):

$$
\int_0^\infty{\rm d}x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)
$$

and I need to cut off the integration and sum at some high value of x and n, respectively. The functions $$f_n(x)\sim \frac{a_n-b_n}{c_n-d_n}$$
look like this and diminish for higher values of n.

With`NIntegrate` I can get around the error message by increasing the `WorkingPrecision` to a certain to a certain point. This was my first choice solution to the problem but then the whole program takes a lot of computational time, as I need to compute a huge amount of points.

In the following, I tried to replace the integral over x by a Gaussian quadrature to improve the computational time. With this solution I am running again into the problem of overflow. This time though, I have no control parameter like `WorkingPrecision` in the case of `NIntegrate` to get around the problem.

I suspect that at certain values of x and n the denominator consists of a substraction of very small numbers. Since Mathematica resorts to machine number precision if not specified otherwise, it is like dividing over zero.

I would like to stick to the idea of replacing the integral by a gaussian quadrature, but is there **a way to control the precision of numbers in a sum**?

I know about `N[x, Precision]` but it is not working in my sums. The program always sticks to machine precision instead, thus leading to the overflow error.

#### Edit

I think the code is too long to post it here, as it is a very longy and complicated function. f is the function under study, n the summation index. R is a parameter, om is the integration variable.

```
In: f[2, n, 1, 1, om] /. {n -> 1, R -> 3.16*10^-6, om -> 3*10^13}
Out: 0.000484331 + 0.0216804 I
```

For higher sum index n, the number gets very small or rather zero for the specified parameters R and om.

```
In: f[2, n, 1, 1, om] /. {n -> 100, R -> 3.16*10^-6, om -> 3*10^13}
Out: -5.057392809172020*10^-482 + 3.553535804695703*10^-477 I
```

And for even higher sum index, I get the error

```
In: f[2, n, 1, 1, om] /. {n -> 200, R -> 3.16*10^-6, om -> 3*10^13}
Out: Indeterminate
```

along with the following messages:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/(0. + 0. I) encountered. >>
>   Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0. + 0. I) ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

The problem is that in the final program I need the sum to go to this high values of n, as there is a non negligible contribution for other values of parameters R and om.

#### Edit 2

The code is:

```
f[P_, l_, muM_, epsM_, om_] := 
  -KroneckerDelta[P, 1] *
     (mus[om]/muM SphericalBesselJ[l, Sqrt[epss[om] mus[om]] R om/c0] * 
        D[Rs SphericalBesselJ[l, Rs], Rs] - 
        SphericalBesselJ[l, Rs] D[Rstilde SphericalBesselJ[l, Rstilde], Rstilde]) /
          (mus[om]/muM SphericalBesselJ[l, Sqrt[epss[om] mus[om]] R om/c0] * 
             D[Rs SphericalHankelH1[l, Rs], Rs] - 
             SphericalHankelH1[l,Rs]D[Rstilde SphericalBesselJ[l, Rstilde],Rstilde]) -
   KroneckerDelta[P,2]*
     (epss[om]/epsM SphericalBesselJ[l, Sqrt[epss[om] mus[om]] R om/c0] * 
       D[Rs SphericalBesselJ[l, Rs], Rs] - 
       SphericalBesselJ[l, Rs] D[Rstilde SphericalBesselJ[l, Rstilde], Rstilde]) / 
       (epss[om]/epsM SphericalBesselJ[l, Sqrt[epss[om] mus[om]] * 
          R om/c0]D[Rs SphericalHankelH1[l, Rs], Rs] - 
          SphericalHankelH1[l, Rs] D[Rstilde SphericalBesselJ[l, Rstilde], Rstilde]) 
   /. {Rs-> Sqrt[epsM muM] R om/c0, Rstilde -> Sqrt[epss[om] mus[om]] R om/c0}

c0 = 299792458; 
omp := (903./100.*eV)/hbar; 
omt:=(267./100.*10.^-2.*eV)/hbar; 
eV = 1602/1000*10^-19; 
hbar = 1055/1000*10^-34; 

epss[om_] := 1 - omp^2/(om(om + I omt))
mus[om_] := 1
```

Leading to the inderminate result posted above for the given parameters.

Comment: This really needs full code in order to have any chance of a proper diagnosis.

Comment: First I would plug in numbers in `{7.36315*10^13,1.10447*10^14}` to see which is happening, `Overflow[]`, `Indeterminate`, or `Infinity`. From there I could probably figure out why. What to do about it depends on how one could feasibly transform the function, at which point heed Daniel's comment.

Comment: Clearly you have a `0/0` situation: Fix it.  (Sorry, can't tell you how without the code.)  It might be like `(Exp[x] - 1)/x /. x -> 0`, which won't be handled by `Simplify`. But something like `Simplify[f[2, n, 1, 1, om] /. n -> 200] /. {R -> 3.16*10^-6, om -> 3*10^13}` might work.

Comment: It looks to me you need to become acquainted with Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic features before proceeding with your work. Suggest you google on "Mathematica arbitrary precision arithmetic".

Comment: Can you come up with a simpler function which demonstrates the same problem?

Comment: Please see my code for demonstration in my OP above. How to fix or get around this inderminate result as I need to go for values n->200 for other sets of parameters. Recall that I want to integrate this whole function over om and have a "infinite" sum over n.

I looked into "Mathematica arbitrary precision arithmetic" but don't know how to apply it in my case. Simply putting N[] around my function doesn't seem to work, especially in the Gaussian quadrature later on.

Comment: Has anybody an idea how to solve my problem?